# facebook log in

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm working on integrating a facebook connect to my application and I have 2 problems:

1.
`LBLoginViewController` is the view that presents as the app launches.
I want to use the storyboard to put some ui elements but for some reason that I don't understand I cannot do that manually, only in code. How can I use the custom class `LBLoginViewController`?

2.
after the log in success I manage to load a view controller. I wont to load a `UITabBarController` but the method I'm using cannot do that. Which method can I use to do so?

this is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// the view controller that load after log in
    ListOfJobs *rootViewController =
    [[ListOfJobs alloc] init];


    UINavigationController *navController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // if the user logs in, do nothing - the root view is already up
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state
        == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        NSLog(@"User Logged In");
    }
    //create and present the login view controller
    else {
        LBLoginViewController *loginViewController =
        [[LBLoginViewController alloc] init];
        [rootViewController presentViewController:
         loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a UIViewController to your storyboard and then set its class to LBLoginViewController using the identity inspector.

Comment: Can you give an example of an element that you cannot add in storyboard?

Comment: ui image for exsample, can i set it by code onley , without adding new property ?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should do for 2 is to assign your TabBarController as your root view controller

`self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;`

and open LBLoginViewController as a modal view at the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

You can always check first if your user has already authorized your app with something like this:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];

} else {
    //open login view
}
```

Comment: i try to assign TabBarController as my root view controller,  bat when it load the tabs is empty.   and what do you mean by "open LBLoginViewController as a modal view at the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

Comment: You need to first setup the TabBarController viewControllers property. What I meant when I said "modal" is to present the view controller like this: [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];